# GAE datastore fetch taking too long?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a query which looks like this:

```
userBase = UserEntry.all().filter('debug =', False).filter('disabled =', False).filter('first_message =', False).fetch(200)
```

And an index (built and serving)

```
 - kind: UserEntry   
   properties:
   - name: first_message
   - name: disabled
   - name: debug
```

There are around 1000 entries in UserEntry, and after filtering out - only 200 which are being fethed.

**The problem:**

The aforementioned fetch, that single line of code, takes **1,5s** to complete. Any ideas why this could be?

My guess is that there might be something wrong with the UserEntry model. It has quite a few properties - but I don't know where to start looking..

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the entities once you've fetched them?

Comment: display them to the user in one long list (yeah, no pagination)

Comment: Is that query slow every time? Are the entities too big? Forexample entities has long TextProperty, it will be slow.

Comment: Yes, that query is slow every single time. I also suspect that the entities might be too big - but I don't know where to start trimming them off. Except for TextProperties, anything else to look for?

Answer (score 1):

Your custom index appears to be in the wrong order; the query is most likely being done by a zigzag merge-join rather than using your custom index. Try filtering the properties in the same order they're in `index.yaml`.

Comment: nope, virtually no change. I don't really think this is an indexing issue - even without one, I doubt it takes GAE 1.5s to fetch 200 from a 1000 records..

Comment: I wonder - is it possible that I keep too much data in one entity? Average record is 1kb big, so 200 records = 200kb to fetch...

Answer (score -1):

The fetch number is too big, try fetch(200) and see how long it taken.